# Graph API を用いた拡張属性の取得ができない

Tags: api

AD Connectを使って、Azureと同期させたのですが、
同期させた際の拡張属性 
`extension_{ID}_{attribute_name}`

が Graph APIで取得できなくて困っております。

旧APIの
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users
こちらでは取得できるのですが、

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`
ではどうやっても取得できないため、そもそも対応しているのか
ご存知の方ご教示いただきたいです。

Comment: すいません。旧API取得できないと記載ありますが、旧APIでは取得できます

Comment: 質問は後からでも自由に [編集] できるので、必要に応じて見直してください。

Comment: [Querying extensionAttributes in Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54584746/9014308) が関連してそうですが解決してませんね。他に [onPremisesExtensionAttributes リソースの種類](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/graph/api/resources/onpremisesextensionattributes?view=graph-rest-1.0), [ユーザーの取得](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) とか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
そうですね。 onPremisesExtensionAttributes  は オンプレ環境の `extensionAttribute1` に紐づいて取得してくるようなので、解決していないですね。

オンプレAD -> Azureに同期するとき、例えばフリガナなどは以下のような形で連携されるみたいです。

"extension_xxxxxxx_msDS_PhoneticLastName": "furi_hoge",
"extension_xxxxxxx_msDS_PhoneticFirstName": "furi_hoge",
"extension_xxxxxxx_msDS_PhoneticDisplayName": "furi_hoge",

この値については、レガシーのAPIでは取得可能な認識でございます。

Answer (score 1):

コメントいただいたみなさますいません。
解決しました。

権限の問題だったようです。

Directory.ReadWrite.All (Readのみでいけそうですが)を付与で、
取得できるようになりました。

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxxxx@sample.com?$select=id,extension_xxxxxxx_msDS_PhoneticLastName
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(id,extension_xxxxxxx_msDS_PhoneticLastName)/$entity",
    "id": "xxxxxxxx",
    "extension_xxxxxxxxx_msDS_PhoneticLastName": "furi_hoge"
}
```